# LLava: deepspeed can not detect editable installed python package/module

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, deepspeed

I have installed a package (llava model from github) as `python install -e .`

In my conda env, I have load llava as:

```
>>python
>>import llava
```

I put import in a .py file, when I used "`python main.py`. I can import `llava`. But using `deepspeed` in shell file as :

```
deepspeed main.py --args
>> sh run.sh
```

It given me error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llava'
```

Note that same configuration works on one system but not the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pip install -e .` command as provided in Readme.